# Check the type of derived class

Tags: c++

In my program I have a class named Entity. Another class Invader inherits Entity. Since I want to have 4 different kinds of invaders, I declare classes Invader1, Invader2, Invader3 and Invader4 which inherit from Invader. Now I declare a Entity pointer type vector to store all Invaders like:

```
entities.push_back(new Invader4());
entities.push_back(new Invader3());
entities.push_back(new Invader2());
entities.push_back(new Invader1());
entities.push_back(new Invader0());
```

When I check the type of the element in entities at runtime, say

```
typeid(*entities->at(index))
```

It may return one of the 4 kinds of invaders. In entities there are also other objects which inherit Entity. So i just want to check if the type of the object is Invader or not, I don't want to know if it is Invader1, Invader2, etc.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: The need to know the class at runtime indicates a bad design. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There will be many ways to do this in C++, but the fundamental problem is that once you have to start querying elements in a container that is supposed to be polymorphic you might as well give up on the idea of using polimorphism. The whole point of having collections of polymorphic elements is that you can treat them all the same. So if you have a `vector<Entity*>` you should only treat its elements as `Entity*`s. If you find that you need to call some `Invader`-like functions on an `Entity`, then you are better off holding a container of `Invader*` too (using the same pointers as for the original container).

Comment: I completely agree. This is the whole point of the liskov principle!

Comment: yes you are right. it's kind of embarrassing to use type check when you try to use polymorphism. but for some rare cases it seems that i have to check the type and make the objects function differently. ill try to improve the structure of my program. Thx for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You could check whether `dynamic_cast<Invader*>(entities->at(index))` returns not `NULL` (as it would result in a `NULL` pointer when the pointer is not pointing to an object whose class is derived from `Invader`).

See [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/) for some documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Create an `Invader` class which inherits from `Entity`. Have your `Invader1`, `Invader2`, etc. classes inherit from `Invader`.

You may then add a `virtual bool IsInvader() const;` which returns `false` in `Entity` and `true` in `Invader`.

Comment: And then add an `isWhatever()` to `Entity` each time you write a class that derives from `Entity`?

Comment: @juanchopanza what about `virtual const char* getClassName() const;` then?

Comment: @moooeeeep it is almost as bad. A design where you have to query each element in a "polymorphic" collection loses all the benefits of polymorphism and isn't scalable at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza My query is not an "isWhatever() to Entity each time you write a class that derives from Entity?". It is clearly a boolean query which captures common properties of certain entities, though not all of them. You are querying for a certain semantical property which happens to be logically tied to the type, not for the type itself.

Answer (score 1):

Just asking this question usually means you're actually missing a virtual function in your interface.

If you have something like:

```
if (myEntity->Type() == TypeInvader)
{
  static_cast<Invader*>(myEntity)->invade();
}
```

You can almost certainly refactor it by adding

```
virtual void tryInvade() {/* normally, entities don't invade*/}
```

in your Entity and

```
virtual void tryInvade() {invade(); /*but invaders do!*/}
```

in your Invader class.

Another option is to never "lose" the type of your entities. If you don't want to use virtual functions for cases like this, chances are, that you shouldn't store those entities by referring to their base-class pointers, but as pointers to the classes you actually want to use. That is, you just keep the type of the entity around instead of asking for it later. This would probably be a sign that you shouldn't have used inheritance tho, since you would have violated the [liskov substition principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) respective storage.